# "Ходить врукопашную"? Чем заменить?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

> Однако в те времена ты внимательно выбирал место, строил на века и
>   должен был уметь отстоять своё право на жизнь в самом прямом смысле. И
>   ведь некоторые короли и даже папы **ходили врукопашную**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь требуется дополнение, например: **ходили врукопашную *на неприятеля***. Без дополнения это может означать что-то вроде "хождения безоружными" (а то и "на босу руку").

Answer (score 2):

У слов "идти врукопашную" есть вполне опеределенный и понятный смысл. Зачем их заменять?

Во многих местах советские солдаты обороняются до последнего патрона, а затем идут **врукопашную**. [Валентин Бережков. Рядом со Сталиным (1971-1998)]

Лариса Голубкина, народная артистка России: - Стрелять, идти **врукопашную**―кому ума недоставало. [ЧЕМУ НАУЧАТ ПРИЗЫВНИКОВ ЗА ГОД СЛУЖБЫ? // Труд-7, 2008.04.03]

И что же, каждый раз надо будет идти **врукопашную**? [Мамедова Майя. КТО ХОЗЯИН МОЕЙ ЗЕМЛИ? // Труд-7, 2006.07.20]